# When can I get away with not declaring int with signed?

Tags: c, types, printf, undefined-behavior

In C, signed integers like -1 are supposedly supposed to be declared with the keyword `signed`, like so:

```
signed int i = -1;
```

However, I tried this:

```
signed int i = -2;
unsigned int i = -2;
int i = -2;
```

and all 3 cases print out -2 with `printf("%d", i);`. Why?

Comment: How are you printing them out? `printf("%d")` with an unsigned would be undefined behavior. Why do you think signed integers need `signed`?

Comment: I used printf("%d", i);

Comment: Show how you're printing it. If it's `printf("%d", i)` then note that `%d` is the format specifier for a *signed integer*; use `%u` to print an unsigned value.

Comment: `unsigned int i = -2;` because implicit conversion(by adjust range) remember here `-` is an operator. simple `2` is singed too, and for assign unsigned you should do like: `unsigned int  i = 2u`.

Comment: Is using %d with an unsigned really undefined behavior? You're still passing in the right number of bytes, so you're not going outside your allowed memory. I always imagined it's reinterpreting the bits in a way I don't want, but I never considered it undefined.

Comment: And remember the important difference between the `signed` and `unsigned` their ranges!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you confirmed you are printing using:

```
printf("%d", i);
```

this is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the unsigned case. This is covered in the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which also covers `printf` for format specifiers, it says in paragraph *9*:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup>[...]

The standard defined in section `3.4.3` *undefined behavior* as:

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

and further notes:

> Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

Finally, we can see that *int* is the same as *signed int*. We can see this by going to section `6.7.2` *Type specifiers*, in paragraph *2* it groups *int* as follows:

> int, signed, or signed int

and later on says in paragraph *5* says:

> Each of the comma-separated sets designates the same type, except that for bit-field[...]

Comment: What do you mean by undefined behavior? It printed out -2. Do you mean that anything can happen?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton yes anything can happen, added link.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: “Undefined behavior”, as it is frequently used in answering C questions, means the C standard does not impose any requirements on the behavior. It does not mean anything can happen, because there are still requirements from the C implementation, the computing system, logic, and the laws of physics.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton "undefined behavior" means that anything can be printed, including printing of what you may think is the correct value. However, this behavior is non-portable. For example, on hardware where negatives are represented as sign+value, the number printed would be different.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have to agree that wording is an exaggeration, your wording is more precise.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually, the whole point of UB is that all the requirements get thrown out the window in the face of UB. And although the laws of physics still apply, your computer could still eg blow up in principle since there have been cases of software being used to cause battery cells to overheat.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton Realistically, it's a safe bet that in most implementations, `unsigned u = ...; printf("%d", u);` will be equivalent to `printf("%d", (signed)u)` since `printf` will react to the `%d` format by interpreting whatever bytes were passed in as a `signed int`, which (in most implementations) is equivalent to casting to `signed int`.

Comment: On a related note, what is the default qualifier for integers declared without signed or unsigned?

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Undefined behavior is defined in C 2011 (N1570) 3.4.3, which says “behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements”. It is quite clear: The **only** requirements that get “thrown out the window” are the requirements of “this International Standard”. It is false to state that “all the requirements” get thrown out the window. If a battery overheats because of software, then the equipment violated other safety standards it is required to obey; improper C code does not excuse that.

Answer (score 3):

The way an integer variable is printed, is subjected to the format string that you pass to `printf`:

- If you use `%d`, then you'll be printing it as a signed integer.
- If you use `%u`, then you'll be printing it as an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` has no way of knowing what you pass to it. C compiler does the default type promotions on passing the arguments, and then the function itself *reinterprets* the values in accordance with the format specifiers that you pass, because it has no other information regarding the type of the value that you passed.

When you pass an `unsigned int` to `printf` in a position of `%d`, it is undefined behavior. Your program is incorrect, and it could print anything.

It happens that on hardware that represent negative numbers in two's complement representation you get the same number that you started with. However, this is not a universal rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int i = -2; // i actually holds 4294967294
printf("%d", i); // printf casts i back to an int which is -2 hence the same output
```

Comment: There is no cast in `printf("%d", i);`. There is also no conversion. In many C implementations, there will be a reinterpretation of bytes as a different type, but this is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: 'reinterpretation of bytes as a different type' is called casting. Isn't it?

Comment: No. Casts are defined in C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.4. They have the form “**(** *type* **)** *expression*”. The cast operator converts the **value** of an expression to another type. Conversions are defined in 6.3. For example, when an integer 3 is converted to floating-point, the value is still 3, but the bytes representing it are different. Reinterpreting bytes means taking the bytes that represent a value in one type and decoding them as if they were another type. For example, reinterpreting the bytes for the float `3.f` as `unsigned int` often produces 0x40400000.

Comment: To summarize: A cast is an **explicit expression in source code** to perform a conversion. A conversion is a operation on the **value** of an object to produce a different type (usually with a similar or related value). Reinterpretation of bytes is a **new decoding** of the bytes

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 things going on:

1. Signed and unsigned are different ways of interpreting the same 64 (or 32, or whatever) bits.
2. Printf is a variadic function which accepts parameters of different types

You passed a signed value (-2) to an unsigned variable, and then asked printf to interpret it as signed.

Remember that "signed" and  unsigned have to do with how arithmetic is done on the numbers.
the printf family accepts internally casts whatever you pass in based on the format designators. (this is the nature of variadic functions that accept more than one type of parameter. They cannot use traditional type safety mechanisms)

This is all very well, but not all things will work the same.

Addition and subtraction work the same on most architectures (as long as you're not on some oddball architecture that doesn't use 2's complement for representing negative numbers
Multiplication and division may also work the same.
Inequality comparisons are the hardest thing to know how they will work, and I have been bit a number of times doing a comparison between signed and unsigned that I thought would be ok, be cause they were in the small signed number range.

Thats what "undefined" means. Behaviour is left to the compiler and hardware implementers and cannot be relied to be the same between architectures or even over time on the same architecture.