# why the output in negative (using bitwise-not)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
void main()
{
        unsigned int a = 10;
        a = ~a;
        printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

the output is `-11`

10 = 1010

~10 = 0101

why the output is negative?

Comment: Use `printf("%u\n", a);` and try again.

Comment: @timrau the output now is 4294967285

Comment: Try "%x", it'll be more obvious than in decimal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: int's size must >= 16 bit, char >= 8 bit. There's no 4-bit data type in C

Comment: possible duplicate of [When can I get away with not declaring int with signed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733651/when-can-i-get-away-with-not-declaring-int-with-signed)

Answer (score 2):

Use %x to view the consistent hex result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
        unsigned int a = 10;
        printf("%x\n", a);

        a = ~a;
        printf("%x\n", a);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
fffffff5
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `~1010` is not `0101` but `11111111111111111111111111110101`. All 32 bits of the value are reversed, not only the bits up to the highest set bit.

As the 32nd bit is set in the result, it's negative.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is for *signed* decimal integer. Use `%u` to print an *unsigned* integer in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

use %u instead of %d because printf treats your variable according to %d or %u. u for